# How to split data into various columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an assignment where I have to split the data into several columns depending on the info. 
The csv file provides first name, last name, email, and class number.
This is what I typed into the terminal:

```
load data local infile"bbclean.csv" into table classinfo fields terminated by " ";
```

but then my work got messed up in the table, since the class info and email aren't separate by " ", but by ",".

[image: example of data table]

Is there a way I can do both, so I can separate the class and email?
This is the method we learned in class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a placeholder variable for the field in the file, then split it up when assigning to the table columns.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "bbclean.csv"
INSERT INTO TABLE classinfo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
(firstname, lastname, @email_and_class, @ignore)
SET email = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@email_and_class, ',', 1),
    class_number = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@email_and_class, ',', -1)
```

Replace all the column names with the actual columns in your table.